# Way to connect to connected objects from outside without configure internet box

Tags: networking, esp32

I don't really understand the way the things works:

How connected plugs can be switch from an external device (not in the local framework)?
I understand that a way is to configure personnal internet box to allow connections from outside using   public ip.
But I have bought a plug, and configure it  as said in the documentation without to need to configure my box. I only give my wifi codes, and the pairing was automatically. And then it is enough to allows me to switch the plug from outside via application without being connected to my local network. 
How this is possible? how this works? Anyone could give me some useful docs about that, because I want make my own connected objects (using esp32).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103774/discussion-on-question-by-xax-way-to-connect-to-connected-objects-from-outside-w).

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, it seems that the common way to do that is to keep persistent bi-directionnal connection between plug and server, for example with MQTT as mentioned by @hardillb

Another possibility seems to be to use uPnp to map port on the internet box, but I don't know if this works always and then can be feasible for a public product.